# Having problems getting idl declaration with pointer to vector for a getter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I am trying to specify a vector in an IDL specification of property getter.
I am new to C++ so bear with me. The object `IThis` is a hypothetical object of anything.
I am getting a compile error at the id declaration expecting a type specifier. Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
STDMETHOD(get_ThisList)(vector<IThis*> *value) 
{
   *value = mThisList;
   return S_OK;   
}

vector<IThis*> mThisList;

[propget] IDLAPI ThisList([out,retval] vector<IThis*>* value);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `vector` in a COM interface, with IDL or otherwise. You could return a safearray of interface pointers; it would look like this:

```
// In IDL
[propget]
HRESULT ThisList([out,retval] SAFEARRAY(IThis*)* value);

// In C++
HRESULT get_ThisList(SAFEARRAY** value);
```

Other alternatives include a [conformant array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367081.aspx) (though this is inadvisable for an automation interface, as yours appears to be), and a separate collection object that represents a list of objects.

An implementation for `get_ThisList` might look something like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP MyObject::get_ThisList(SAFEARRAY** value) {
  if (!value) return E_POINTER;

  SAFEARRAYBOUND bound = {mThisList.size(), 0};
  *value = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UNKNOWN, 1, &bound);

  IUnknown** data;
  SafeArrayAccessData(*value, (void**)&data);
  for (int i = 0; i < mThisList.size(); ++i) {
    (data[i] = mThisList[i])->AddRef();
  }
  SafeArrayUnaccessData(*value);
  return S_OK;
}
```

Error handling is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This seemed to work! But how do I convert my object I have stored as a vector to return a SAFEARRAY now? Or are they same thing?

Comment: Use use [safearray API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221145.aspx). I added a simple example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector is a C++ class; IDL (interface definition language - different language) has no concept of it.

"expecting a type specifier" means the IDL compiler doesn't recognize std::vector as a type.

You will have to return a pointer to array of IThis as the return value, and put it into a smarter object at the caller's site.